# Requiring another package from your package in Package Control?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I'm developing a plugin for SublimeText that uses the [FullScreenStatus](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FullScreenStatus) plugin. Is there a way to set it up so that if someone installs my plugin, the FullScreenStatus plugin will be automatically installed as well, like a `requires` directive? Every other package manager I know of can do this, but I couldn't find anything in the docs and no other package I looked at is trying to require another package.

Since FullScreenStatus is MIT licensed, I could just include it in mine, but is there a way to `require` it without doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to bundle it yourself, or explain in the install message and README there is an external dependency. If you feel like adding to the discussion on dependency management, feel free to contribute to https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/166. Some initial work can be seen at https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/291#issuecomment-14028788.